# How to include a different probability distribution in TMB in R?

Tags: r, tmb

I am using the TMB package in R, and I want to use a density distribution which is not available in the [R style distribution](https://kaskr.github.io/adcomp/group__R__style__distribution.html).

How should I include it? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

For example, I want to use Simplex distribution, which I have already written in R:

```
dsimplex <- function(y, mu, sigma, log=TRUE){
  dis <- (y-mu)^2 / (y*(1-y)*mu^2 *(1-mu)^2)
  dsim <- -0.5*log(2*pi) -0.5*log(sigma) -
    (3/2)*log(y*(1-y)) - (1/(2*sigma))*dis
  if(log == FALSE){dsim <- exp(dsim)}
  return(dsim)
}
```

and it is available in `simplexreg` and `Stan` packages.

- What is the best approach to deal with it? (I would like to have an external file which contains this density, and call it from the file that I am writing my log likelihood)

Comment: I'm thinking that asking at the github/TMB (also) about this and reporting back the results here would help others that want to template their particular distribution would be helpful.

Comment: Tks, I just posted it there as well https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tmb-users/3_ElYPKPoJ4

Comment: In the last paragraph of https://kaskr.github.io/adcomp/_book/Tutorial.html it says how.
And in the TMB group (link above), they also answered.